# Cannot convert from int to ApiModels.Enums.EnumStuff

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The two errors that it is giving are,cannot convert from in to ApiModels.Enums.ContentAreaEnum and the best overloaded method match for '' has some invalid arguments I am trying to display a simple list from the database using a repository, API model, and a service.I do not have much experience working with either so I would like to get a full understanding of the errors.

In my index I am attempting to display the content, but I am getting the errors.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    ViewData["Claims"] = _ctsService.GetClaimsForContentArea(id);
    return View();    
}
```

This is the IService I am referencing:

```
List<Claim> GetClaimsForContentArea(ContentAreaEnum contentArea);
```

The Service:

```
public List<Claim> GetClaimsForContentArea(ContentAreaEnum contentArea)
{
    return _claimRepository.GetClaimsInContentArea((int)contentArea);
}
```

The Repository:

```
public List<Claim> GetClaimsInContentArea(int contentAreaId)
{
    var query = from c in _db.Claims
            where c.ContentArea_ID == contentAreaId
            select c;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

The IRepository:

```
List<Claim> GetClaimsInContentArea(int contentAreaId);
```

And the ApiModel:

```
public enum ContentAreaEnum
{
    Subject1 = 1,
    Subject2 = 2
}
```

Comment: Ok, what ID is passed to GetClaimsForContentArea() method?

Comment: First, copy and paste the exact errors you're getting from the console output, the lines they're occurring on, and the the relevant lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are refering to compilation errors.

Since your method signature looks like `List<Claim> GetClaimsForContentArea(ContentAreaEnum contentArea);` and you are trying to pass `int` to it, it won't work.

You have to either transform your int to enum or cast enum to int like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{

    ViewData["Claims"] = _ctsService.GetClaimsForContentArea((ContentAreaEnum)id);
    return View();

}
```

but then you don't need another transformation to int. I think you should change your `GetClaimsForContentArea()` method signature to `GetClaimsForContentArea(int id)` and cast this parameter to enum right there or get rid of whole transformation which doesn't seem necessary.

EDIT:

If you really need validation of `int id` value, you can add following code:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{

    if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ContentAreaEnum), id)) {
       ViewData["Claims"] = _ctsService.GetClaimsForContentArea((ContentAreaEnum)id);
    }

    return View();

}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying but ContentAreaEnum is a non-nullable type which is not compatible with the 'as' operator. Your first suggestion worked perfectly.